# Как наложить кнопку на image?

Tags: html, css

я пытаюсь наложить кнопку на изображение, способы которые я искал работают через `position: absolute`
Но я так и не смог сделать сайт адаптивным с таким подходом
Вот мой код

```
<div class=“section2”>
    <div class=“item”>
         <img src=“…”>
    <div class=“item2”>
         <button>Скачать</button>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Может быть всё проще и можно привязать к нажатию на картинку действие, которое должны была бы выполнить кнопка? Хотя это было бы уже не просто вёрстка и стили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле подход с `position:absolute`, на мой взгляд, правильный. У Вас в коде не закрыты теги, прежде всего, плюс нет стилей, с которыми Вы пытались сделать кнопку по центру, поэтому сложно сказать, что сделано неправильно.
Вот рабочий вариант:

```css
    .section2 {
        position: relative;
        width: fit-content;
        height: fit-content;
    }
    .item2 {
        height: fit-content;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        width: fit-content;
    }
```

```html
<div class="section2">
    <div class="item">
         <img src="...">
     </div>
    <div class="item2">
         <button>Скачать</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, огромное спасибо за ответ. 
Писал вопрос поздно и без использования компьютера. 
Способ работает